# Why caffe model is saved as PCX image?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, protocol-buffers, caffe

I am trining `Deep Learning` using [caffe](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/).

I saved the model as

```
    string savemodelname = Conf.snapshot_prefix_folder+"/snapshotat_"+ss.str()+".caffemodel";                    
    caffe::NetParameter net_param;
    net_->ToProto(&net_param);
    caffe::WriteProtoToBinaryFile(net_param, savemodelname);
```

But it is saved as PCX image (image/vnd.zbrush.pcx) and not in binary.

My OS is Ubuntu16.04.

What is wrong with that?
I use c++ for my training.

EDIT:

How model is saved can be seen in the attached image.
[image]

Comment: how can that be? your savemodelname is completely different! do you have a file at savemodelname? isn't this file the saved model??

Comment: @Shai Let me show you how model is saved in attached image. Please see in EDIT.

Comment: I think this PCX type is a guess (and not a very good one) by your OS. Try and load the model using caffe and see if you are getting the same model.

Comment: @Shai But I have .caffemodel file in binary file format in the same PC. But they are, I just download from internet and not by using this caffe::WriteProtoToBinaryFile() api.

Comment: Can you open the saved model using caffe?

Comment: Haven't tried yet. I am still training. Using python, I have transformed from h5 to caffemodel before, I could see binary file. i'll test and update later.

Comment: look at [binary file headers list](https://www.garykessler.net/library/file_sigs.html) PCX files has `0x0a` first byte. It might be the case that your `.caffemodel` happens to have the same first byte and that confuses your OS to think it is a PCX image.